# Find n from summation

Tags: summation, poisson-distribution

I ran into this expression while reading through a chapter a book:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{e^{-1500}1500^i}{i!} \ge 0.95$$

And they solve for $n$ and got $n = 1564$ from the expression, but there's no detail on how to get $n$. Can someone explain how to get that number for $n$?

The book is Discrete Event System Simulation by Jerry Banks. This is in the 5th Edition, Chapter 6 Example 6.15, if anyone wants to look this up.

Comment: Is it possible the author used Mathematica (or some other mathematical software) to determine $n$? I can offer one or two techniques to solve for some such $n$, but I'm not sure anything is quite as tight as $n=1564$.

Comment: That might have been the case. I tried to crunch this in wolfram alpha and couldn't get the answer.

Comment: The Poisson probability distribution for a mean of 1500 will be approximately a normal distribution. The probability to be 1.64485 sigma above the mean is 5% for a normal distribution, therefore you would roughly estimate n to be $1500 + 1.64485 \sqrt{1500}\approx 1564$

Comment: @CountIblis That makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability distribution is the [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) with $\lambda=1500$.  For large $\lambda$ the distribution is approximately normal with mean $\lambda$ and variance $\lambda$, so standard deviation $\sigma=\sqrt \lambda$.  For a one-sided normal distribution you have $5\%$ of the area above mean + $1.648 \sigma$, which here is $1500+1.648 \sqrt {1500} \approx 1564$

Answer (score 1):

From a purely algebraic point of view
$$\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{e^{-1500}1500^i}{i!} =\frac{\Gamma (n+1,1500)}{\Gamma (n+1)}$$ So, you could consider that we look for the zero of function
$$f(x)=\frac{\Gamma (x+1,1500)}{\Gamma (x+1)}-0.95$$ which is not very well conditioned. Better will be to search for the zero of
$$g(x)=\log \left(\frac{\Gamma (x+1,1500)}{\Gamma (x+1)}\right)-\log(0.95)$$ Remembering that 
$\frac{\Gamma (m,m)}{\Gamma (m)} < \frac 12$, let us use Newton method with $x_0=1500$. Since $g(x_0) <0$ and $g''(x_0) <0$, by Darboux theorem, we shall not face any overshoot of the solution which is $x=1563.485020$.

Just for the fun of it, ask Wolfram Alpha to plot $g(x)$ for $1500 \leq x \leq 1600$.